# How can I suppress Extraction rule error in load test and make the test marked as pass?

Tags: load-testing, webtest

In my web test, I have used a loop to redirect it to the previous request if it fails to get the expected response which includes a context parameter param01.

So, when I run a load test sometimes the loop 1 fails because it cannot find the Context parameter param01 and throws an extraction rule error, but loop2 becomes success because it found the context parameter and extraction rule is passed.

Now, I want to suppress the Extraction rule error which occurs in the failed loop (loop 1) and pass the test. Please help me on this.

Comment: Can we guess your code? *If so, we'd sell your code.*

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add tags for the load testing system you are using, eg Visual-Studio or LoadRunner or Jmeter or whatever. My answer assumes you are using Visual Studio.

Comment: Has your question been answered? If not then please [edit] it to make it clearer. If it has been answered then please read about [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Many extraction rules have a `Required` property, of boolean type. Set it to `False` so that the rule (and hence the test) will not fail when the expected data is not available.

Be aware that the extraction rule for `Extract regular expression` has a `Required` property but it appears to be handled wrongly in some Visual Studio versions . See [this fault report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1267015/webtest-extract-regular-expression-required-false-does-not-work). See also [this discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6303940a-ab36-4d91-bc52-ced1f977dabb/extraction-rule-failing-test?forum=vstswebtest) of the issue plus a work-around that calls the real extraction rule then writes `true` to the `Success` field.